# Fortran module segmentation fault- GNUFOR

Tags: fortran, gnuplot

I need a special library for Fortran so that I can code and visualize on the fly, instead of writing to a text file then use either Python or Matlab to plot. I followed this:

https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/gnufor/gnufor.html

The instructions are not cleared so I did not use their examples, so I wrote my own code. There are 2 files: **gnu.f90** from website, and **myplot.f90**, which I wrote like this:

```
program myplot


    !Declare data types
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: N1 = 50
    real(kind=8)       :: x1(N1),x2(N1)
    real(kind=8)       :: y1(N1)
    real(kind=8)       :: y2(N1)
    integer            :: i

    !Generate 2D plot

    do i = 1,N1
        x1(i) = i
        x2(i) = i
    end do

    y1 = x1**2
    y2 = x2**3

    !print *, 'Plotting'
    !call plot(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    call write_xy_data(x1,y1)   

end program myplot
```

Apparently, from their **gnufor.f90** file, I only need to do:

write_xy_data(X,Y) and it should work.  In their example code, they did not use gnufor.f90 as a module so I didnt put:  use gnufor at the beginning. Although, I tried that and it didn't work as well. So in my current directory, I have:

**gnufor.90 
myplot.f90**

And to compile it, I am on Linux: `gfortran myplot.f90 -o test`
The error was:

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

    Backtrace for this error:
    #0  0x7FB0B051DE08
    #1  0x7FB0B051CF90
    #2  0x7FB0AFF574AF
    #3  0x40302F in write_xy_data_
    #4  0x400D7E in MAIN__ at myplot.f90:?
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I expected the problem to be in my own code, although all array sizes are declared.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the interface of the subroutine `write_xy_data`.  It's quite likely you are not calling it correctly.  [If there is a module available, why aren't you using it?]

Comment: What did you try to start? You say your compilation line is `gfortran myplot.f90 -o test` but shouldn't this be `gfortran gnufor.f90 myplot.f90 -o test`

Comment: The backtrace shows that problem is in write_xy_data, which you did not show.  gfortran comes with a number of options that aid debugging.  These might help you.  See your documentation.

Comment: I don't know Fortran, but the calling signature for [write_xy_data](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/gnufor/gnufor.f90) is `subroutine write_xy_data ( data_filename, n, x, y, ierror )`, so you might be missing some arguments. Did you try to compile [their example](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/gnufor/gnufor_prb.f90)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subroutine `write_xy_data` in **gnufor.f90** from the website you linked has a signature

```
subroutine write_xy_data(data_filename, n, x, y, ierror)
    implicit none
    character ( len = * ) data_filename
    integer ( kind = 4 ) n
    real ( kind = 8 ) x(n)
    real ( kind = 8 ) y(n)
    integer(kind = 4) ierror
```

Which means instead of passing only `x,y`, you have to call it as

```
call write_xy_data('myfile',N1,x1,y1,ierr)
```

passing as arguments the name of the file to write to (`'myfile'` in the example), the number of points to write (`N1`), the data (`x1,y1`) and an integer that carries information on the success of the write (`ierror`, this one has to be declared, too)

Also, there is no module `gnufor`, so no `use` clause is required, all functions in **gnufor.F90** are global, which is also the reason why you need to pass the number of points as an extra argument, as assumed shape would require an explicit interface.